# What could be a case of Throwable when app calls AudioManager.setSpeakerphoneOn()

Tags: android, android-audiomanager

Not always on some devices I get such exception which cause crash:

```
? I/AudioManager: setSpeakerphoneOn false java.lang.Throwable
at android.media.AudioManager.setSpeakerphoneOn(AudioManager.java:1235)
at com.mj.callapp.device.media.MediaPlayerWrapper.setLoudspeakerState(MediaPlayerWrapper.kt:47)
at com.mj.callapp.device.media.MediaPlayerWrapper.<init>(MediaPlayerWrapper.kt:75)
```

my code is very simple and it looks like this:

```
var loudspeakerState: Boolean? = null
    set(value) {
        if (value != null && value != field) {
            field = value
            audioManager.isSpeakerphoneOn = value //line 47
            loudspeakerStateSubject.onNext(value)
        }
    }
```

So anybody has similar issue? Any clue what cause it?

Comment: I have the similar issue. A little strange, but it doesn't crashes my app, only dumps the stack trace to logcat. Tried to play with AudioManager setMode() - NORMAL, IN_CALL, IN_COMMUNICATION but with no success. For now I have no solution or idea. Because the app doesn't crashes, decided to ignore it and concentrate on app's core functionality.